# Chebyshev's Inequality and confidence level

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with VarX=1.2. We take random samples from X and average them. What's the minimum number of samples that should be taken to assure that the average deviates from $\mathbb{E}X$ by not more than 1.8 with probability at least 0.95?

So as I understand the Chebyshev's inequality should be

$ P(|X - E(X)| > 1.8) = 1.2 / 1.8^2 $

$P(|X - E(X)| \le 1.8) = 1 - 1.2 / 1.8^2$

$\Rightarrow p \approx 0.63$

I was trying to use the Z score of 1.96 level of accuracy with $p \approx 0.63$ to get the number of observation as 358. But this is not correct. Can someone suggest, a correct way to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: How are you using that $1.96$ number?

Comment: Z score for confidence level of 0.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have used the law of large numbers. We are choosing a random variable from X as $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ and their $mean = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}{n}$. Also, $mean \rightarrow \mathbb{E}X$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence to assure that the average deviates from EX by not more than 1.8 with probability at least 0.95, we may use the Law of Large numbers as follows:

$P(|X_n - \mathbb{E}X_n| > \epsilon) = P(|X_n - \mathbb{E}X| > epsilon) = \frac{var\bar{X_n}}{\epsilon^2}$

$P(|X_n - \mathbb{E}X| > epsilon) = \frac{var\bar{X_n}}{\epsilon^2}$

but

$var\bar{X_n} = \frac{varX}{n}$

$\Rightarrow P(|X_n - \mathbb{E}X| > \epsilon) = \frac{varX_n}{n\epsilon^2}$

$\epsilon = 1.8; varX = 1.2$

$\Rightarrow 0.95 = \frac{1.2}{n \times 1.8^2}$

$\Rightarrow n = \frac{1.2}{0.95 \times 1.8^2}$

$\Rightarrow n = 7.40741$

$\Rightarrow n \approx 8$